# CentOS7 firewalld and open ports

Tags: centos, firewalld

I have firewalld process enabled and I have explicitly opened certain ports. Here is the output of it:

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
```

and the output is

```
443/tcp 4789/udp 2377/tcp 7946/udp 7946/tcp 2376/tcp 2375/tcp
```

I am still able to access and connect to port 80 on this machine. What is it that I am doing wrong? I only want the above ports to be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands and find out what zones you have active:

`firewall-cmd --get-default-zone`

`firewall-cmd --get-zones`

`firewall-cmd --get-active-zones`

Also enabling a service doesn't necessarily mean you started it...have you run the following?

`firewall-cmd --state`